# Efficiently read-modify-write text file in c#

Tags: c#, file-io

```
 private void AlterFile(string fileName)
    {
        StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
        bool isAltered = false;
        lock (LockObj)
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileName))
            {
                string currLine;
                currLine = reader.ReadLine();
                while (currLine != null)
                {
                    content.AppendLine(currLine);
                    if (currLine.Contains(KeywordToSearch))
                    {
                        isAltered = true;
                        //insert data in string builder to be inserted here
                    }
                    currLine = reader.ReadLine();
                }


            }
            if (isAltered)
            {
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileName))
                {
                    writer.WriteLine(content.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to read a text file from disk, insert a few lines in between, and then write the file to the disk. Considering this operation is to be called in a for each loop for about 1000 files, I find this way to be quite inefficient. 
Is there a better solution for this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: use Linq to load the file and you can also use that to do a searh on a word.. also why are you using `lockObj`? you can bulk load the file and read from the file without having to use a locking mechanism

Comment: What size are the files? It's probably more efficient to read the entire file into memory, Then parallel process multiple files simultaneously instead of streaming them.

Comment: @JamesB: His problem isn't the processing time. He's I/O bound. Bulk reading the file might give a *slight* performance increase. Parallel processing would just complicate things and give no appreciable performance benefit.

Comment: No, there really isn't a better solution. If you want to modify a text file, you have to read the whole thing and then rewrite it.

Comment: @JamesB: Files range from 100 kb to 3-4 MB. There could be upto 100-200 requests at a time so that means at peak time, server will have to hold (3MB * 200)= 600 MB. Thats why I'm avoiding loading entire file in memory.

Comment: You have the [time-memory trade off](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space%E2%80%93time_tradeoff) problem, you can be fast or you can have a small memory footprint, which is your goal? You are not clear which one you would rather have. If your goal is speed I have a question, does the function that calls AlterFile need to know when the alteration has been finished or can it dump the work on a queue for it to be processed later? If so that opens up a LOT of performance options (like using the producer-consumer model and the TPL for a worker)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain :thanks for your response. AlterFile can not be asynchronous :(